# wxpython: wx.Window DefaultSize

Tags: wxpython, size

Experts:

How does everybody avoid this situation?

Situation:
With a following wxpython script,

self.label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Blah Blah")

The text "Blah Blah" does not show correct. Only a part shows.

It turned out to be that following script works correct.

self.label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Blah Blah", **size=(300,20)**)

It took almost a week for me to get to the following page.

[wx.Window](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Window.html) reads "If no suitable size can be found, the window will be sized to 20x20 pixels so that the window is visible but obviously not correctly sized."

Any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown any code and so we do not know the context of your issue.

Using a panel on the frame and sizers, (which is the [recommended way of structuring a wxPython application](https://wxpython.org/pages/overview/), the label displays correctly

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_text = 'Wx App'

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Blah Blah")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.label)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. Yes, your code works. Yes, I should have posted the problematic code. It is a part of a long script by somebody else. Yes, I trimmed too much. Side by side comparison shows that super() is missing in my code. Many other lines exist in my code. I need to figure out how much to trim.

Comment: I'm pleased to have helped. Please accept the answer if it has solved your problem, and you can mark the answer as useful if it has helped develop your understanding of the issue

Comment: I regret, but still I have not been able to pinpoint the problem in my original code. I will update once I find it.